# Clase solamente elimina un registro con clausula IN (Array)

Tags: php

Desde un formulario envío `$_POST['seleccion']` que es una lista de códigos, la cantidad varía según se seleccione en el formulario.
En el controlador separo los códigos e invoco a la clase:

```
$eliminar = implode(',', $_POST['seleccion']);
$eliminaAlumno = new Alumnos();
$OK = $eliminaAlumno->eliminar($eliminar);
```

La clase es la siguiente:

```
public function eliminar($lista) {
    $bd = new Conn();
    $IN = str_repeat('?,', count($lista) - 1) . '?';
    $sql = "DELETE FROM tabla WHERE cod IN ($IN)";
    $sth = $bd->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(1, $lista, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
}
```

Usé como base esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array) le agregué ***bindParam*** para verificar que todos los códigos sean ***Integer***.
El problema es que solamente elimina un registro y no todos los códigos que recibe. Cuál es el problema?

Comment: si haces un `echo $sql` que muestra?

Comment: Muestra `DELETE FROM tabla WHERE cod IN (?)` y si hago un `echo` a `$lista` se muestra los códigos, en este caso 3 códigos: `1234,5666,3456`

Comment: Pregunto por la consulta sql final que genera tu código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `PARAM_INT` hace una conversión a entero por lo que sólo te toma el primer id que pases,  para evitar esto debes establecerlo como `PARAM_STR` ya que lo que estas pasando es un String no un entero, es decir, el `bindParam()` debería quedar asi:

```
$sth->bindParam(1, $lista, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Puedes revisar las Constantes predefinidas de PDO aquí: http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.constants.php

Debes tener en cuenta que una lista de enteros es diferente de un número entero:

Ejemplo:

```
echo (int) '1,2,3,4,5';  // 1

echo (int) 1;  // 1

echo (string) '1,2,3,4,5'; // 1,2,3,4,5
```